# How to upgrade ubuntu packages on VPS with a working website?

Tags: ubuntu, vps, apt-get

So I have a VPS that my site runs on and I want to upgrade the ubuntu packages because it says there are some that have security holes, so I wonder if I just should turn my site off, ssh to the vps, use `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, restart it and start the site again? Is there a chance that new packages will break anything? And if so, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Mostly upgrade packages do not break the websites but it is recommended to take web files backup before make any package upgrades. Additionally, you can take backup of whole VPS from the VPS management portal provided by your web hosting provider. Hence, in case anything goes wrong you can easily restore your VPS from the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wait 24 hours before downloading and applying upgrades, there's a very good chance that the major kinks would be worked out... But if you have multiple servers serving the same site, there is other solutions.